# Как работать с TO_NUMBER с запятой

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

```
SELECT TO_number('94.188', '99.999')
 FROM dual;
```

Если например **94,188** уже не работает нужно чтоб работал с запятой

Comment: Вы не решили задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
SELECT to_number('94,188', '99D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', '' ')
  FROM dual;
```

У функции `TO_NUMBER` есть параметр, указывающий, какой разделитель целой и дробной части и разделитель групп использовать. В этом случае, конечно, в маске надо указывать D и G вместо конкретных символов.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в Вашем примере замените запятую на точку.

```
SELECT TO_number(REPLACE('94,188', ',', '.'), '99.999')
 FROM dual;
```

Все зависит в каком контесте используется. Разделяете ли вы дробную часть или показываете разряды числа.